# Cassandra map collection returned by node.js Helenus looks odd

Tags: javascript, node.js, cassandra, cql3

I have a CQL3 table in Cassandra that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table (
  usr text,
  box text,
  uidseq map<bigint, text>,
  PRIMARY KEY (usr, box)
)
```

I do a query in cqlsh like so:

```
select uidseq from table WHERE usr = 'usr' AND box = 'box';

uidseq
------------------
{1: 'a', 2: 'a'}
```

Looks great, until I run the same query through the Helenus package for node.js and JSON.stringify'd the resulting value returned and get this back:

```
[0,2,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,97,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,1,97]
```

I tested the value returned by Helenus and it does come back as an object, so I am not sure where I have gone wrong here?

Comment: Ok so now my logging is showing the value of uidseq is a buffer (<Buffer 00 02 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 01 61 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 01 61>).  Converting it to a string using toString('utf-8') I get back the letter a.  Say wha?

Comment: Have you tried using [the Node.js driver for CQL](https://github.com/jorgebay/node-cassandra-cql)? It returns maps as Javascript objects (key / values). 
Disclaimer: I'm developer on that project

Answer (score 2):

Appears to be a bug with the helenus package https://github.com/simplereach/helenus/issues/113.